# Factors, system and so on...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x+y=1$; $x^{2}+y^{2}=221$; what is $(x³)+(y³)$ ?

I already solved this problem, but I wanna know if there is an easier way to solve it, because I'm studying for a very hard exam and I must learn how to choose the best tactic to solve math problems. 
Check out what I did:

$x^{3}+y^{3}$

$(x+y)[x^{2}-xy+y^{2}]$

$(x+y)[x^{2}+2xy+y^{2}-3xy]$

$(x+y)[(x+y)^{2}-3xy]$

$(x+y)^{3}-3xy(x+y)$

$1^{3}-3xy1$

$1-3xy$

Then:

$x=1-y$

$(1-y)^{2}+y^{2}=221$

$1-2y+y^{2}+y^{2}=221$

$2y^{2}-2y-220=0$

$y=\frac{-(-2)±\sqrt{(-2)^{2}-8(-220)}}{4}$

$y’=(-10)$; $y''=11$

$x+y=1$ $\therefore$ $x=11; y=(-10)$

Then we have:

$1-3*11(-10)=331$

And that's the answer!

My question is: There is an alternative way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit you're question using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @FineMan It's almost done, but I dunno how to edit that formula with fraction and square root.

Comment: fraction: `\frac{a}{b}`turns to $\frac{a}{b}$.
root: `\sqrt{a}` turns to $\sqrt{a}$.
This info is available in the link of my first comment.

Comment: @FineMan Done, man, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted proof is essentially correct, but note that the first half is not really necessary since you calculate the actual values of $x,y$ in the second half.

Regarding `x=11; y=(-10)` you should make a note that the system is symmetric in $x,y\,$, so $x=-10, y=11$ is a solution as well, but it doesn't matter which pair you choose since the expression to calculate ($x^3+y^3$) is itself symmetric in $x,y$.

> There is an alternative way to solve this problem?

- $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \implies xy = \frac{1}{2}\left((x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2)\right)=\frac{1}{2}(1-221)=-110$
- $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y) \implies x^3+y^3 = (x+y)^3-3xy(x+y) = 1 + 3 \cdot 110$

Comment: Thanks!!! I really don't know how  you guys solve these problems so quickly.

Comment: @NicolasLeskiu Glad it helped. As for solving, practice works wonders. Once you've seen (and solved) enough of them, you'll recognize the patterns more quickly.